# prevent people from looking into website directory

Tags: php, html, css

Hello all i am having a website in which i have many directories like members/images/emotions and other php files like index.php,login.php,profile.php... etc
in the directory/folder images all the imgeas of wbsite is stored and i do not want people to look into it. currenlty when we type www.sitedomain.com index.php is shown which is ok but when we type www.sitedomain.com/images all the images link are shown i dont want any people to look into this folder . a default 404 eror page should be displayed

Comment: How you configure your server to not display directory indexes depends on the server you are using.

Comment: i just want to show 404 error page when any one tries to browse my website's folder and that too by coading

Comment: By coding what? PHP? How is the server going to know to run your PHP?

Comment: If you don't want resources to be publicly accessible put it outside your doc root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a `.htaccess` file in the folder with the following line in it:

```
Options -Indexes
```

Or (if your site doesn't run on Apache or you don't have override permission)

- put an empty `index.html` file in the folder

Or

- put an `index.php` file in the folder with the line:

  `<?php
      header('Location: some-other-page.html');`

Comment: Maybe. This assumes that the server server is Apache and is configured to allow overrides.

Comment: @Quentin What do you suggest? Shall I edit my answer then or rather delete it?

Answer (score 1):

Upload a file called 'index.html' to the directory 'images'. Your server is displaying this message because it is unsure which file is the index file.

Below is a template for your html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>404 Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>404 - Page not found</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but when they will type www.mydomain.com/images/imagename it will be displayed

Comment: Yes the image will be displayed - There is no way I know of of preventing this unless you try 'hotlink prevention'. I am afraid this is how the internet works

Comment: That will return a `200 OK` page displaying the text of a 404 error. That is … not good.

Comment: i dont want to be displayed it is very private folder it should be access denied for all

Comment: @user3467320 then you should delete the folder, or move it out of the document root - problem solved.